# How to give FTP address in java?

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

I have written the code which downloads the file from FTP server. Since I have my FTP server locally and I want to access like "ftp://localhost/alfresco". It was alfresco's FTP.

I have the following Code

```
public class FtpTransfer {
public static final void main(String[] args)
{
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    FileOutputStream br = null;
    try
    {
        ftp.connect("ftp://localhost/alfresco");
        ftp.login("admin", "admin");
        String file = "KPUB//Admin//TMM//Pickup//TMM_TO_ARTESIA_06152010220246.xml";

        br = new FileOutputStream("file");
        ftp.retrieveFile("/"+file, br);
        System.out.println("Downloaded...");
    }
    catch(IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("Error : "+exception);
    }
}
}
```

The following exception occurs.

```
Error : java.net.UnknownHostException: ftp://localhost/alfresco
```

Please let me know how should I give the FTP Host Address?

Comment: another note, when ftping to other domains like mysite.com, you can either pass in ftp.mysite.com or mysite.com to the connect method. but ftp://mysite.com will not work.

Comment: Once retrieved, where my downloaded file resides.

Comment: It will be in the directory where you ran your program from

Comment: also many files need to be transferred as binary, so to put FTP in binary mode type:  ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

Comment: Can we explicitly give the dir where the retrived file must reside.

Comment: yes, that's what you define in the `FileOutputStream`, so for example: `FileOutputStream br = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\casonkl\\Desktop\\new_pic_name.jpg");` Then `ftp.retrieveFile("pic_name_on_server.jpg", br);`

Comment: btw, I called my instance of ftpClient ftp..

Comment: you can also specify the path in `ftpClient.retrieveFile("PATH\\file");` or `ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("folder/subfolder/");` then you won't have to specify the full path in `retreiveFile`

Comment: If I want the retrieved file to be stored in some location say "c:\Downloaded", then how do we wanna proceed?

Comment: I went ahead and consolidated all my notes into an answer, I think it should address your exact questions.

Comment: Apologize me. Haven't looked at your solution and posted this comment kenny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example demonstrating connection to a server, changing present working directory, listing files in a directory and downloading a file to some specified directory.

```
package test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

public class FtpTransfer {
 public static final void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
  FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
  ftp.connect("ftp.somedomain.com"); // or "localhost" in your case
  System.out.println("login: "+ftp.login("username", "pass"));

  ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("folder/subfolder/");
  // list the files of the current directory
  FTPFile[] files = ftp.listFiles();  
  System.out.println("Listed "+files.length+" files.");
  for(FTPFile file : files) {
   System.out.println(file.getName());
  }
   // lets pretend there is a JPEG image in the present folder that we want to copy to the desktop (on a windows machine)
  ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); // don't forget to change to binary mode! or you will have a scrambled image!
        FileOutputStream br = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\casonkl\\Desktop\\my_downloaded_image_new_name.jpg");

  ftp.retrieveFile("name_of_image_on_server.jpg", br);
  ftp.disconnect();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Am getting the problem solved. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

```
FTPClient f = new FTPClient();
f.connect("localhost");
f.login(username, password);
FTPFile[] files = listFiles(directory);
```

**Also See**

- [Article from JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html)
- [JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)

Comment: I'm not sure if "username" and "password" are valid parameters anymore. I just downloaded the latest commons.net jar and the only params are String hostname, InetAddress address, and int port (in various combinations)

Answer (score 2):

Try remove protocol ("ftp://") from your url.

And please, look at the [example](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

Answer (score 1):

The [`FTPClient.connect()`](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#connect%28java.lang.String%29) method takes the *name* of a server, not a URL. Try:

```
ftp.connect("localhost");
```

Also, you may need to put `alfresco` somewhere else. If it's part of the file path,

```
String file = "alfresco/KPUB//Admin//TMM//Pickup//TMM_TO_ARTESIA_06152010220246.xml";
```

Comment: +1. Its working Greg. Thanks. In my code I had given the file name. Instead of that, I have give the path and I need to list the file names inside that path. Is it possible. If so please give me your valuable suggestions. Thanks once Again .