# how to open ftp in windows explorer using java

Tags: java, ftp, explorer, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to open a ftp address like
 `ftp://myaddress`
in windows explorer using java and I'm using this code :

`Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("ftp://myaddress"));`

but I get this exception :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: ftp:\myaddress doesn't exist.

and this code is working for any local address like "D:\myfolder "

and the ftp address is easily accessible using windows explorer when I enter that manually !

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Instead of using `open` try with `browse`

Comment: @Mubin: I want to open the address in windows explorer while `browse` opens that in default browser !

Comment: The problem is because you are trying to poen ftp:\myaddress that is not a valid ftp direction, this is because java interpretate ftp://myaddress as ftp:\.

Comment: @Deckard27: Yes I know , so what's the solution ?  :)

Comment: Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562536/how-to-give-ftp-address-in-java?rq=1, i think is a good answer t ypur question